# Solve $x^2 y''+(-2x-x^3)y'+5y=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Ok so for me I am having trouble solving this equation to get

$y=C_1y_1+C_2y_2$, but I'm having trouble dealing with the (-2x-x^3) part.  Usually I would isolate $y''$, then make $y=x^m$, then go from there, but I'm having trouble dealing with the $(-2x-x^3)$ part.  Thanks!

When I tried that approach, I got $[x^{3/2}x^{x^2/2}x^{(\sqrt{x^2+6x-11})/2}, x^{3/2}x^{x^2/2}x^{-(\sqrt{x^2+6x-11})/2}]$ form a basis, but it just seems too complicated when I need to solve

$y_1(1)=-4, y'_1(1)=5, y_2(1)=-5,y'_2(1)=5$

The point is to find the Wronskian, $w(x)=y_1(x)y'_2(x)-y_2(x)y'_1(x)$ for x>0

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are attempting? What do you mean isolate $y''$?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives a very complicated solution for this equation. Check, if the exercise is really like that!

Comment: I have added detail to the problem, and it's part of the fundamental set of solutions ${y_1, y_2}$ that follow the four conditions above, and then to find the Wronskian

Comment: Your solution is less complicated than Wolframs solution seems to be. Wolfram also shows hypergeometric functions. But perhaps, they can be simplified. Just check if your fundamental system solves your equation.

Comment: I have not looked at Wolfram but this is the right problem!

Comment: Most definitely I have edited it

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following.

By Liouville-Ostrogradski formula,

$$W(x)=W(1)e^{-\int_1^x \frac {-2t-t^3}{t^2}dt}=
5e^{\int_1^x 2t^{-1}+t dt}=
5e^{2\ln t+t^2/2|^x_1}=
5e^{2\ln x+x^2/2-1/2}=
5x^2e^{(x^2-1)/2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

the wronskian $w= y_1y_2' - y_2y_1'$ of the equation $ay'' + by' + cy = 0$ satisfies the able's equation $$ a\frac{dw}{dy} + b w = 0.$$  we have $ay_j'' + by_j' + cy_j = 0, \,  j = 1, 2.$  considering $$a\frac{dw}{dy} = ay_1y_2'' -ay_2y_1'' = -y_1(by_2'+cy_2) + y_2(by_2'+cy_2) =-bw$$  establishes the abel's equation.

in your case you have $$\frac{dw}{w} = -\frac{b}{a} = \frac{(2x+x^3)dx}{x^2} = (\frac{2}{x} + x)\, dx $$

on integration you get $$w = Cx^2e^{x^2/2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $u=x^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{dy}{du}\dfrac{du}{dx}=2x\dfrac{dy}{du}$

$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(2x\dfrac{dy}{du}\right)=2x\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{dy}{du}\right)+2\dfrac{dy}{du}=2x\dfrac{d}{du}\left(\dfrac{dy}{du}\right)\dfrac{du}{dx}+2\dfrac{dy}{du}=2x\dfrac{d^2y}{du^2}2x+2\dfrac{dy}{du}=4x^2\dfrac{d^2y}{du^2}+2\dfrac{dy}{du}$

$\therefore x^2\left(4x^2\dfrac{d^2y}{du^2}+2\dfrac{dy}{du}\right)+(-2x-x^3)2x\dfrac{dy}{du}+5y=0$

$4x^4\dfrac{d^2y}{du^2}-2x^2(x^2+1)\dfrac{dy}{du}+5y=0$

$4u^2\dfrac{d^2y}{du^2}-2u(u+1)\dfrac{dy}{du}+5y=0$